# Is there a way to list all actions registered by a plugin or theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'd like to override a function registered using `do_action()` by a third party theme or plugin. `remove_action()` looks to be the way to do this but its not working in my particular case. Is there a way to list all actions registered by a theme or plugin, including their priority values e.g. using `wp cli`?

Perhaps something which iterates over and displays a pretty output of all levels of the `$wp_filter` array?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [Debug bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin and the Debug Bar Actions and Filters Addon